# How do I create an uber source jar with Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Is there a well-known way to create an uber source jar? In other words, a jar of all the source code for a project and all its dependencies (or at least those that have a -sources.jar)?

I've looked into doing it with the maven-assembly-plugin, but using a `dependencySet` with includes of `*.*.*.sources.*` (or `*.sources`) doesn't work because those are not actually dependencies of the project, and I don't want to add them *all*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create an uber jar. Just include the following within your `<build>` tag -

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>source-jar</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
          <artifactSet>
            <includes>
              <include>...</include>
            </includes>
          </artifactSet>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

To modify the configuration, you can use [Resource Transformers](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html) within `org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource` package.

And to define the contents of the jar, you can further use [includes and excludes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) within the filters.

Comment: This works, but also creates an (unwanted) shaded jar...I just want the sources.  Also, if any dependencies don't have a sources jar, I get a ``NullPointerException``, so I had to add an includes list to get just my own corporate sources.

Comment: @Ben well infact, that should differ from user to user and that's why I shared the link for the same. Thanks for the edit as well. Also if this helps, please be kind to accept it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found some information on [working with sources in the maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/using-dependencies-sources.html).

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
        <id>src-dependencies</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>sources</classifier>
          <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/sources</outputDirectory>
          <includeGroupIds>{your group prefix}</includeGroupIds>
          <includes>**/*.java</includes>
          <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```

So if I do that, and then run a maven-assembly-plugin referencing the unpacked files, I can do it in two steps.

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <execution>
        <id>uber-source</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>ubersource.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <outputDirectory>${deploy.internal.directory}</outputDirectory>
          <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

with a file set in the assembly descriptor ubsersource.xml:

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>${project.build.directory}/sources</directory>
  <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
```

And then I get my uber source jar...

There is perhaps a subtle distinction in the way the maven-assembly-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin treats `sources`.  If you reference classifier `sources` in a `dependencySet` of an assembly descriptor, it looks for sources that are actual dependencies in your pom -- not that useful.  However, in maven-dependency-plugin, referencing `sources` classifier means that sources *of* your dependencies.  Hence why this solution works.

I also wrapped this up in my own plugin using [mojo-executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor/tree/master/mojo-executor) to make it single step, and single declaration in my pom, but that's optional

This is a lot more pom code, but I like it better than the maven-shade-plugin because it does just what I want, and nothing more.